# excel vba change format of date - numbers

Tags: excel, vba

Excel changes the following values automatically to a number, I guess because he considers them as a date:

2/2/1 becomes 36527
4/2/1 becomes 36926

I have a column with a combination of different formats now:

```
2/1/
3/1/
8/7/
36527
1/0/0
36926
```

Which VBA code can I use to convert the numbers back to their original format? The other values should stay the same.

I know the cDate function, but I guess it's not useful here?

I have already this in my VBA code for pasting values

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Columns("A:AH").NumberFormat = "@"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: before importing or inputting the values, change the cells to text.  Excel will then not change them to dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change them back. Once Excel converts them, the original value is gone. Before you input the value, you can prepend an apostrophe to force it to text.

```
ActiveCell.Value = "'" & sMyValue
```

or as @Scott Craner commented, you can format the cell as text

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"
ActiveCell.Value = sMyValue
```

Comment: I had already this in my VBA code ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Columns("A:AH").NumberFormat = "@"
             ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Range("A1").Select
             ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: If you paste, it will overwrite the formatting. It's best to set the Value property rather than paste. But if the value you need is only in the clipboard, then paste special so you don't overwrite the formatting.